# Retrieve Variable from URL mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buongiorno
devo recuperare una variabile da url in mvc, come posso fare?
esempio
Devo recuperare **NNN** dall'url, inserirlo in un input form html.

```
https://localhost:7249/Candidati/AssCodBarre/0/BLFRCC81E17F839N/**NNNN**
```

Hello I have to retrieve a variable from url in mvc, what can I do? example I need to retrieve NNN from url, insert it into an html input form.

```
https: // localhost: 7249 / Candidati / AssCodBarre / 0 / BLFRCC81E17F839N / NNNN
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Path Name:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

It will return: `"/Candidati/AssCodBarre/0/BLFRCC81E17F839N/NNNN"`

Than:

```
var arr = pathname.split("/");
```

Assume your variable is always in the last position. So,

```
var _val = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

"_val" contains your desired variable value.